# Overlapping lines in plot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I'd like some help to create a similar plot like image 2. I don't know if the problem it's my data or code. But as you can see in the first graphic there is an overlap and I'd want a graphic more soft as a second image.
On the other hand. Could someone to order the dates?

````
ggplot(data = consum, mapping = aes(x = Month, y = Cpc, color = Year, group = 1)) +
      geom_line() +
      facet_wrap(~Type) + 
      theme_bw() + 
      scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "blue"))
```
````

[image]

```
structure(list(Month = c("January", "Frebrary", "March", "April", 
"January", "Frebrary", "March", "April", "January", "Frebrary", 
"March", "April", "January", "Frebrary", "March", "April", "May", 
"January", "Frebrary", "March", "April", "January", "Frebrary", 
"March", "April"), Cpc = c(52.6030417616108, 52.3807979985595, 
63.4812345277527, 69.9337994172852, 4.87131485047933, 5.10130976154746, 
5.81295804297682, 6.85707419263629, 7.155082484813, 7.24882986945935, 
8.32846647323954, 9.80847493902699, 6.94921351149698, 6.55179853175549, 
7.35259139659446, 6.95037273611445, 8.03280438298055, 4.60674099035869, 
4.47914291992134, 4.95627076108138, 4.57283076670216, 51.3581426441543, 
47.660340330082, 52.8289135861524, 50.6656566779732), Year = c("2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019"
), Type = c("Total feeding", "Total feeding", "Total feeding", 
"Total feeding", "Fresh vegetables", "Fresh vegetables", "Fresh vegetables", 
"Fresh vegetables", "Fresh fruits", "Fresh fruits", "Fresh fruits", 
"Fresh fruits", "Fresh fruits", "Fresh fruits", "Fresh fruits", 
"Fresh fruits", "Fresh fruits", "Fresh vegetables", "Fresh vegetables", 
"Fresh vegetables", "Fresh vegetables", "Total feeding", "Total feeding", 
"Total feeding", "Total feeding")), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Comment: Does replacing the geom with `geom_line(aes(group = Year))` help in some ways?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added `geom_line(aes(group = Year))` and works fine!